# Whitelisting an IP address in nginx ingress controller

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

I have a service behind an nginx ingress controller. I want to restrict access to it based on IP. I added the annotation to the ingress manifest:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "my_ip/32"

The nginx ingress controller's service's externalTrafficPolicy is set to Local by default, but the issue is that the nginx ingress controller is denying me even from my whitelisted IP.

When I hit the server I get this in the nginx controller log: `access forbidden by rule, client: 127.0.0.1, server: my-site.datasite.com`

I'm using GCP GKE.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure the value of `my_ip` is actually your IP address?  Is your client machine behind a proxy or NAT gateway?

Answer (score 0):

The annotation nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "IP" will override some of your config. As mentioned in [Nginx docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#whitelist-source-range):
“Adding an annotation to an Ingress rule overrides any global restriction”.

Another option is to use ConfigMap [whitelist-source-range](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#whitelist-source-range). Like mentioned in [this example](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html), you can use ngx_http_access_module.

As in Nginx config, each path is saved as

```
location / {
  …
}

location /api {
  …
}
```

you can add these restrictions there. Below example:

```
location / {
    deny  192.168.1.1;
    allow 192.168.1.0/24;
    allow 10.1.1.0/16;
    allow 2001:0db8::/32;
    deny  all;
}
```